# Multiple use of a template in the same page in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have some repetitive components on my AngularJS page such as billingAddress, shippingAddress and primaryAddress. I have created a separate template file for address components and expected to be able to use ng-include to include the template thrice on my page. I am unable to find documentation around passing models to templates. What I am looking for is something like

```
<div ng-include="address.tpl.html" ng-model="{address: primaryAddress}"></div>
<div ng-include="address.tpl.html" ng-model="{address: billingAddress}"></div>
<div ng-include="address.tpl.html" ng-model="{address: shippingAddress}"></div>
```

Is this even possible as of now?

Comment: why not to make it as a directive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

his is for what directives are made.

```
angular.module('docsSimpleDirective', [])
  .directive('myAddress', function() {
    return {
      scope: {
          address : '='
      },
      templateUrl: 'address.tpl.html'
    };
  });
```

Then in your template simple use the $scope.address.
On declaring the directive you should use it like this.

```
<my-address address="primaryAddress"><my-address>
<my-address address="billingAddress"><my-address>
<my-address address="shippingAddress"><my-address>
```

Comment: I still think AngularJS should make it easier to pass in models to ngInclude's scope. The best practices lists tell me that directives are meant to be used when you have some DOM manipulation that you can't get away. But, I think directive is the only option I have at the moment.

Comment: Directives are usefull when you need to reuse some code that involves HTML. That is exacly what you needed here.